# Erro ao tentar instalar pacotes no Linux utilizando o comando pip [Linux]

Tags: python, linux, pygame, pip

Não consigo instalar pacotes usando o **pip** no linux, essa é a tela de erro:

````
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sahsjreu/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sahsjreu/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-sahsjreu/pygame/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sahsjreu/pygame/
    Complete output (20 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
    WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
    WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
    Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

A versão do Pygame 1.9.2rc1 introduziu algumas dependências a mais e que em algumas plataformas não são tratadas corretamente.

Tente rodar o código abaixo para instalar essas dependências.

```
sudo apt install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libportmidi-dev libfreetype6-dev
```